# System freezes after turning off WIFI

Tags: wireless, updates, 22.04

I am using 22 version of Ubuntu and when I turn off my wifi the system froze. My laptop is Dell latitude 7480. After that it takes time to work normal but after that the wifi no longer exists so I have to reboot and then the same thing happens.

Comment: Turn WiFi on again and use a variant of `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"`.